# Determine all possible paths of the particle

Tags: calculus

Consider a particle (in $2$ dimensions) that experiences a non-zero force and its speed is constant relative to some fixed point. Besides a circle, what possible paths can such a particle trace over time?

First, some basic work on this problem. We can visualize the particle in the Cartesian plane with the fixed point at the origin. Let the position vector of the particle as a function of time be $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$. The velocity vector is $v(t)=(x'(t),y'(t))$ and the acceleration vector is $a(t)=(x''(t),y''(t))$.

The force on the particle is nonzero, so the magntitude of the acceleration is nonzero, so the accleration vector is not equal to $(0,0)$. Then at least one of $x''(t)$ and $y''(t)$ is not $0$. By integrating this means at least one of $x'(t),y'(t)$ is not constant.

The speed is equal to some constant $C$. For simplicity assume that $C=1$. Thus $\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}=1$, or $x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2=1$. The solution $x'(t)=\cos(t), y'(t)=\sin(t)$ yields the circular path. As an example consider the solution $x'(t)=t, y'(t)=\sqrt{1-t^2}$. By integrating we find:

$x(t)=0.5t^2$

$y(t)= 0.5(t\sqrt{1-t^2}+\arcsin(t))$

To visualize the shape of the path described by this vector get $y(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$ as below:

$y=0.5(\sqrt{2x(1-2x)} +\arcsin(\sqrt{2x}))$

The square roots are only defined if  $0<x<0.5$, equivalently $0<t<1$.  I'm not sure exactly what this means physically, but my interpretation is that this means the particle can only travel that path for a finite amount of time (whereas, in the circle solution the particle can travel the path forever). The plot of this function for $0<x<0.5$ is interesting, resembling a logarithmic graph. See the [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F2+%28sqrt%282x%29+sqrt%281-2x%29%2Bsin%5E%28-1%29%28sqrt%282x%29%29%29).

Of course, infinitely many functions $r(t)$ exist which satisfy the given conditions, but most seem to have strange behaviour. The specific question I have in mind is: are there there any paths which the particle can travel for an infinite amount of time, besides the circle?

By the way, this is not really a physics question, it is in fact a math question which can be rephrased as follows: Consider the vector-function with $r(t)$ with coordinates $(x(t),y(t))$ where with $t$ a real parameter and $x(t),y(t)$ map to the reals. We have that $|r''(t)|$ is nonzero for all real $t$ and $|r'(t)|$ is constant. Find all such functions $r(t)$ that are defined for all $t>0$.

Edit: A simpler but still limited domain solution is $x(t)=2/3t^{3/2}$, $y(t)=2/3(1-t)^{3/2}$ which is defined only for $0<t<1$. This yields $y-2/3(1-(3x/2)^{2/3})^{3/2}$ which also resembles a logarithmic graph.

Edit 2: There is a related, but much easier question, which is the case when the speed of the particle is constant (not relative to a fixed point). I do not exactly know how to phrase this, but as an example consider a car moving on a flat surface. The speed that I am referring to is that recorded by the odometer. So if this speed is constant and the force is nonzero, what paths can the particle take? The answer is any non linear path because we can take any curve (not linear) and travel along that curve at constant speed, the velocity vector is always changing direction, thus the acceleration is nonzero. For example, draw any non linear path on the ground and make a car drive in that path. We can have the car travel at constant speed the whole time, while the acceleration is nonzero.

Comment: I fixed your square roots. Please check if I didn't changed by accident anything important.

Comment: As info: use `{ }` instead of parenthesis for square roots. For example,  `\sqrt{ \cdots }` produces $\sqrt{\cdots}$.

Comment: Think you didn't change anything important. Thanks for the edit!